# Consistent hashing using modulo

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, hash-function

Following my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189643/file-sharding-between-servers-algorithm/21195606#21195606):

Suppose I have *n* servers, and I want to distribute files evenly between them (same number of files on each server).

Initially *n=2* and I use the following function to map a file *f* to a server *n*:
*n = f%2*.

Now I have a new server (*n=3*), and I want to move existing files to the new server, such that all files will be distributed evenly again. For this I use the following scheme:

```
f%6  Old n New n
0    0     0
1    1     1
2    0     0
3    1     1
4    0 --> 2
5    1 --> 2
```

Of course I want to minimize the number of files I move.

To locate a server after the change:

```
f%6 in [0,2] --> n=0
f%6 in [1,3] --> n=1
f%6 in [4,5] --> n=2
```

Now, there is a fourth server available (*N=4*). We need to move 1/3 of the files to the new server (In general, when the *n*th server is added, we need to move 1/(n-1) of the files).

I use the following file redistribution scheme (other schemes are possible as well):

```
 f%12 Old n New n
 0    0     0
 1    1     1
 2    0     0
 3    1     1
 4    2     2
 5    2     2
 6    0     0
 7    1     1
 8    0 --> 3
 9    1 --> 3
10    2     2
11    2 --> 3
```

To locate a server after the change:

```
f%12 in [0,2, 6] --> n=0
f%12 in [1,3, 7] --> n=1
f%12 in [4,5,10] --> n=2
f%12 in [8,9,11] --> n=3
```

In general, I am constructing a [consistent hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing) from *1..[lcm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)(1,2,...,N)* to 1..N.

When N grows, lcm(1,2,...,N) [grows fast](http://oeis.org/A003418/internal), and I don't want to store a huge mapping table.

No to my question:

Is there a way to analytically calculate *server(f)* for a given value of *N* using the suggested method?

(*f* is the file Id, *N* is the number of servers)

Comment: How are you deciding which files to move when $n$ increases?

Comment: @Snowball: the heuristic I used was to move the last instance for each value of Old n, but I don't mind using another rule.

Comment: I think the technique [described here](http://www.tomkleinpeter.com/2008/03/17/programmers-toolbox-part-3-consistent-hashing/) would work fine. It requires a lookup table of size $O(N)$, and the operation to determine which server has a file is $O(\log(N))$.